# Prestashop 1.6 Watermark not applying to old images

Tags: prestashop-1.6, watermark

I have the default watermark module that came with the fresh Prestashop installation. I have only updated it to the latest version.

I recently change my watermark image (.gif) and i wanted to apply it to all of my products (around 4000).

I've uploaded the new .gif image and started regenerating all images.

Everything worked fine and after some time outs i managed to regenerate all images.

The problem was that all the new images were without the new watermark .gif and without the old one.

I've searched for some answers but nothing worked.

Now i have all my images without any watermark. The only way that i can get the watermark to work is to reupload images one by one, because all my new products with new images have the watermark in it.

Can anyone help me? My images are unprotected and my competition is starting to get some images from me.

> Website: www.copertini.pt
>
> Prestashop: 1.6.0.7
>
> Default Watermark Module: 1.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have no missing product images. You should remove that images (links to images) from products.